# Issues with adding/deleting local permissions to Alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, opencmis

I have been trying to add/delete local permissions for a file/folder in Alfresco using open CMIS with mix success. My tests are done on Alfresco 4.2f/5.0a with Apache chemistry CMIS 0.10 on a mixture of Windows, *nix platforms.

When adding roles to the local permissions list, I am seeing Alfresco generated roles such as **All**, **roles.write**, **roles.read**, etc being generated. I have been trying to clean this up through resetting the ACL after adding permissions, but with some mix success.

Secondly, when deleting the **last** local role from the permissions list, I notice that the inherited permissions are now made local for some reason. For instance, if the inherited permissions contained user1 as a Coordinator, this will now also appear in the local permissions list.

I understand that CMIS has some limitations with handling permissions. How do I go about resolving the things I am seeing?

Comment: You may need to reframe your question because it does not seems to convey your thoughts.

Comment: Edited. Hopefully its better.